# Retrieve data from PFRelation in custom class

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to get data from a current user's "addedRelation" but the following code isn't working. I get a warning in the console that says PFRelation is readonly as well.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" containsString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (Friends *currentFriend in objects) {
            self.relation = currentFriend.friendsRelation;
            self.addedRelation = currentFriend.addedRelation;

            self.query = [_relation query];
            self.array = [_query findObjects];
            self.array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.array];

            //    self.addedRelation = [[PFUser currentUser] relationForKey:@"addedRelation"];
            self.addedQuery = [_relation query];
            self.addedArray = [_query findObjects];
            self.addedArray2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.addedArray];

            [self.segmentControl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Friends (%lu)", (unsigned long)[self.array2 count]] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
            [self.segmentControl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Added Me (%lu)", (unsigned long)[self.addedArray2 count]] forSegmentAtIndex:1];
        }
    }];
```

I was wondering what I did wrong in the following code. The last two lines always return 0. Am I not supposed to get a relation online and set it to a local relation?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your line.

```
self.array = [_query findObjects];
```

It takes time to update value of this array. You need to add this line of code in block, after getting objects store it in self.array.

You can replace your code with this one.

```
        self.array2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        self.addedArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
        [query whereKey:@"user" containsString:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            for (Friends *currentFriend in objects) {
                self.relation = currentFriend.friendsRelation;
                self.addedRelation = currentFriend.addedRelation;
                self.query = [_relation query];

                [[_relation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                    [self.array2 addObjectsFromArray:objects];

                    [[_addedRelation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                        [self.addedArray2 addObjectsFromArray:objects];

                        [self.segmentControl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Friends (%lu)", (unsigned long)[self.array2 count]] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
                        [self.segmentControl setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Added Me (%lu)", (unsigned long)[self.addedArray2 count]] forSegmentAtIndex:1];

                    }];
                }];
            }
        }];
```

Hope it helps. Let me know... :)

Comment: It sort of works. For some reason it is displaying the same object twice in the array (with a count of 2) when there is only one in the "addedRelation" for that user in my Parse class online.

Comment: You need to check parse.com table for duplicate values. If this answer solved your issue. please upvote and mark as an answer. So, others can know about it.

Comment: On parse, there's only one row. Are you sure the code you posted doesn't add it in twice?

Comment: See, what i did is modified your code to get all objects. I'm not sure whats the relation between your Friend classes. You need to debug for it.. Maybe its because of one-one relation.. Suppose, A is friend of B, and B is friend of A too .. So, both are added twice as both are each others friend.. You need to check object, relation and query for it.. As far as code is concerned its working perfectly. Hope it helped you!